# How to change the colour of multiple children components when triggered by a single child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

how do you affect multiple (in this case just 2) children components owned by two different parent components when an action is triggered by one of the children components?

For example I have a component, lets call it `<component-one/>`. Inside this component I have something like below:

```
<div @mouseover="hover=true" @mouseleave="hover=false" :class="setColour">
  <div class="icon-wrapper commercial-layout position-relative">
    <u-button icon color="transparent" @click="toggleCommercials">
      <u-icon :icon="icon" color="white"/>
    </u-button>
    <small class="commercial-ind">COMMERCIAL ADS</small>
    <div class="commercial-layout commercial-ind">{{hide}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

computed: {
  setColour () {
      if (this.hover) {
        return 'bg-danger'
      }
      else if (this.commercials) {
        return 'bg-primary'
      }
      else if (!this.commercials) {
        return 'bg-secondary'
  }
},
watch: {
    setColour: function(val) {
      console.log("val",val)
    }
  }
```

But somewhere else in the code base I have two other components, lets call them `<component-two/>` and `<component-three/>`. Inside those components I use `component-one`. When I push on the button from `component-two` I want the same effect to also be triggered in `component-three`, and vice versa,  but I'm not quite sure how to achieve that.

Currently both `component-two` and `component-three` just have `component-one`. I've tried adding a `watch` in `component-one` but it doesn't really do anything other than capturing changes to the `setColour` computed property. (I naively thought by capturing the change, all places where `component-one` is used will get updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your specific component relationships, but in general I recommend using Vuex.

Using Vue 2 and the CLI, I created sample SFCs that use Vuex to store the background color CSS style.  Each child is associated with a specific color, and clicking it's button updates the color of all sibling components.

/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    commonBgColor: 'navajowhite'
  },
  mutations: {
    updateBgColor(state, newColor) {
      state.commonBgColor = newColor;
    }
  }
})
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <child initBgColor="aquamarine" instanceName="One" />
    <child initBgColor="mediumorchid" instanceName="Two" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" :style="currentBgColor">
        <span>Sibling Component {{ instanceName }}</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="updateCommonBgColor">Change All Sibling Colors</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      initBgColor: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      instanceName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        backgroundColor: this.initBgColor
      }
    },
    computed: {
      currentBgColor() {
        return 'background-color: ' + this.$store.state.commonBgColor;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateCommonBgColor() {
        this.$store.commit('updateBgColor', this.backgroundColor);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .child {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
  }

  span {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }

  button {
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```